# Why was I banned from chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

So what is the reason for being banned from chat?

Comment: It looks like you were temp-banned for using inappropriate language.

Answer (score 22):

People can be banned from chat for one of two reasons:

- one or more of their messages is flagged as rude or abusive and the flag is validated by other users;
- they are temporarily suspended by a moderator, usually for inappropriate conduct.

See the [Stack Exchange chat FAQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq), specifically the [Be Nice section](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#nice):

> **Do I have to be nice?**
>
> Yes. We expect community members to treat each other with respect … even when they don't deserve it.
>
> This site is collectively moderated by the community through participatory flagging. If your chat messages are repeatedly being flagged by your peers you might find yourself muted, banned, or – in extreme cases – your The Stack Exchange Network reputation may be negatively affected.
>
> If you see an inappropriate, spam, or offensive chat message, please use the hover menu at the far right of each chat message to flag it. This will draw it to the attention of the community moderators.

More information on the technical workings of chat flags may be found in [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86479/how-do-chat-suspensions-work).

---

In your case, you first posted two messages which were flagged and earned you short suspensions:

- > @Aegon, retrads are retards, what can I say
- > I take the good with the bad, and shit on the bad

This was in the context of you [persistently posting comments accusing people of being "retards" for downvoting your question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEXB7.png), and then arriving in chat to defend your actions and claim that you were just "calling a retard a retard". In view of this, your comments were flagged, the flags were validated, and you got a short automated suspension.

Upon your return from this suspension, you said:

- > OK, I will use spastic from now on

This comment was also flagged and deleted, and then a moderator (not me, although I fully support their decision) gave you a 2-hour suspension from chat. You were showing no sign of learning from your mistakes, despite many people in chat trying to educate you in both the [Be Nice policy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) and basic courtesy. At this point, your insistence on posting insults had gone too far.

Answer (score 17):

Because they do things where a temporary ban in the appropriate response, most often coming in violation of StackExchange's "Be Nice" policy.

I recommend you read it, but the full policy can be summed up as simply "Be nice to people".

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#nice

Comment: The policy on this site should be 'be excellent to one another'

Comment: Maybe another time. Right now I am  bit busy to read something like that.

Comment: @Skooba, my understanding is those who deserve respect get respect?

Comment: @KyloRen It literally says the opposite of that. "We expect community members to treat each other with respect … even when they don't deserve it."