# Why is chat so easily manipulated?

Tags: discussion

Why is chat so easily manipulated?

- Who decides what?
- Who decides bans?
- Who decides what goes on in chat?

Comment: This [main meta on chat moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat) should answer all your questions.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10111/why-was-i-banned-from-chat?rq=1

Comment: @Skooba, I find it funny that the link is to my question as to why I was banned from chat?

Comment: @KyloRen History seems to be repeating itself. Maybe you can learn from it?

Comment: You're back.  And it took you less than a day to question how and why you get moderated, again.  Pretty sure you didn't think through the last action.

Comment: @KyloRen why have you been moderated?

Answer (score 7):

1. > Who decides what?

   Chat moderation is done by moderators, room owners, and all users. Moderators have all the moderation powers, which they can use single-handledly. This includes validating flags, deleting and moving messages, chat suspensions, and kicking. Room owners can move messages and kick (for a fixed time). Every user can flag a message or act upon a message flagged by another user.
2. > Who decides bans?

   See above.
3. > Who decides what goes in chat?

   Chatters. Rooms across the SE network vary widely in their scope, and even in what's allowed there. Certain rooms will give more leeway to language and content, as long as it's SFW and fits some general criteria for content.

   The Restaurant is a fairly new room, so there isn't an established scope (nor should there be, imho), other than it being SFF's room. There are, however, some boundaries.

---

#### What happened now?

I said I posted floofs. You insulted floofs. I disregarder that insult and posted another floof. You ten posted the same message about floofs 3 times. At this point I flagged your message and kicked you. The flag was validated, which (in most cases) means it's not suitable for chat. For the whole time my face was like

[image]

It's as if you were *trying* to get yourself kicked from the room... which resulted in you being kicked. "Manipulating" chat into getting you kicked isn't the flaw of the chat, it's your problem.

Please, do not say stuff in chat that you were saying. This includes, but is not limited to, saying derogatory things about other users, or trying to get them angry. Just be nice, and people will be nice to you. Remember that free speech doesn't mean you are allowed to say anything you want to, and other people don't have to put up with that.

[image: "I can't remember where I heard this, but someone once said that defending a position by citing free speech is sort of the ultimate concession; you're saying that the most compelling thing you can say for your position is that it's not literally illegal to express."]

Comment: Ahh, I see, you can't disagree with the room owner or the “cliquey” community. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10195/is-this-site-cliquey And I never said my rights were violated, I am saying that you have to conform or it is a get out attitude. Nice attitude indeed.